# Magento 2 website is not running in local after moving from host. System getting hanged when running the website

Tags: magento2, memory

We are using Magento 2 for our website. We have used Bluehost with 2GB RAM, 5TB Memory. Bluehost called me yesterday to change the server because of the huge bandwith. We have currently 1000 products in our website. And we need to add 5000 products in future. Server team told us to check the website for taking huge bandwidth. We planned to check the website in local system(Ubuntu 17.10 8GB RAM, 1TB Memory).

Allocated memory size was exhausted when we run website in local system(Ubuntu 17.10). We changed the memory_limit, phpuploadsize, postmaxsize to -1. But this time system getting hanged when we run website and execute any magento ssh commands reindex, cache flush, clean commands.

What is the main reason for this cause? How do i check it?

Comment: First disable the deploy mode from developer to production.

Comment: turn on developer mode now i can access backend. But front end shows error Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: file_put_contents(/opt/lampp/htdocs/website/pub/static/frontend/Sm/topzstore/en_US/css/config_4.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/app/design/frontend/Sm/topzstore/Magento_Theme/templates/html/complie_less.phtml on line 107

Comment: It is due to incorrect file permission to your magento.  Please follow below link to reset proper permission. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: i deployed content using -f. now its working. but category pages shows Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'class': The attribute 'class' is not allowed.

Comment: Yes Please remove it as this is not supported in newer magento 2.2.x version